# Collision detection difficulty, player flies

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, 2d-games

I created a 2d platform game today. The player can move right left and jump. It is NOT allowed to climb up the side of the wall. When you press e.g right & up beside the wall it climbs up the wall. Can you have a look and say what have I missed.

```
function updateMe()
{
    x+=vx;
    y+=vy;

    //gravity
    vy+= gravity;
    if(y>=HEIGHT-playerH)
    {
        y=HEIGHT-playerH;
        vy=0;
    }

    //collision y
    var maxR=WIDTH/tileW-1;
    if(vy>0)
    {
        //going down
        var temp2 = Math.floor((y+vy+playerH)/tileH);
        for(var i=Math.max(0,Math.floor(x/tileW)),len=Math.min(maxR,Math.ceil((x+playerW)/tileW)); i<len; i++)
        {
            if(map[temp2][i]!=0)
            {   
                y=temp2*tileH-playerH;
                vy=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(vy<0)
    {
        //going down
        var temp2 = Math.floor((y+vy)/tileH);
        for(var i=Math.max(0,Math.floor(x/tileW)),len=Math.min(maxR,Math.ceil((x+playerW)/tileW)); i<len; i++)
        {
            if(map[temp2][i]!=0)
            {   
                y=temp2*tileH+tileH;
                vy=0.01;//make it fall down
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //momentum
    if(vx>0)
        vx-=momentum/2;
    else if(vx<0)
        vx+=momentum/2;

    //collsion
    maxR=WIDTH-playerW;
    if(vx>0)
    {
        //going right
        if(x+vx<maxR)
        {
            var temp2 = Math.floor((x+vx+playerW)/tileW);
            for(var i=Math.floor(y/tileH),len=Math.ceil((y+playerH)/tileH); i<len; i++)
            {
                if(map[i][temp2]!=0)
                {   
                    x=temp2*tileW-playerW;
                    vx=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vx=maxR-x;
        }
    }
    else if(vx<0)
    {
        //going left
        if(x+vx>0)
        {
            var temp2 = Math.floor((x+vx)/tileW);
            for(var i=Math.floor(y/tileH),len=Math.ceil((y+playerH)/tileH); i<len; i++)
            {
                if(map[i][temp2]!=0)
                {   
                    x=temp2*tileW+tileW;
                    vx=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vx=x;
        }
    }

    //x boundaries
    if(x<=0)
    {
        x=vx=0;
    }
    else if(x>=WIDTH-playerW)
    {
        x=WIDTH-playerW;
    }

    //draw
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,playerW,playerH);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem most likely due to the order of operation, not looked at it too much, but I believe moving

```
x+=vx;
```

To between

```
else if(vy<0)
{
    //going down
    var temp2 = Math.floor((y+vy)/tileH);
    for(var i=Math.max(0,Math.floor(x/tileW)),len=Math.min(maxR,Math.ceil((x+playerW)/tileW)); i<len; i++)
    {
        if(map[temp2][i]!=0)
        {   
            y=temp2*tileH+tileH;
            vy=0.01;//make it fall down
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
//momentum
if(vx>0)
    vx-=momentum/2;
else if(vx<0)
    vx+=momentum/2;
```

Rather than at the top will mean that you dont have issues of it being moved slightly into the wall and trying to adjust y based on whether it is colliding with something below, which it will be.